# lodsb tasm outputs only last letter from the file

Tags: assembly, x86, byte, buffer, tasm

I don't know where is the problem here, i'm trying to output all the character from file to the screen, but somehow it prints only the last one.
For example if my test.txt file has a line **abc** in it, the output shows us only **c**.
How should i use lodsb properly in this situation?
Don't mind some unnecessary lines in data section, i just pasted not the all code.

**Updated code:**

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
filename db 'test.txt',0 
filename1 db 'temp.txt',0
error_open db 'impossible to open this file$',13,10
error_read db 'impossible to read this file$',13,10
handle dw 0
handle1 dw 0 
buffer db 21 dup 0
counter dw 0

.code

mov dx, @data
mov ds, dx 

mov dx, offset filename
mov al, 2
mov ah, 3dh
int 21h
mov handle, ax
jc erroropening

readbyte_1_file:
inc counter
mov dx, offset buffer
mov bx, handle
mov cx, 1
mov ah, 3fh
int 21h
jc errorreading
cmp ax, cx
jne close_1_file     ;bytes actually read
jmp readbyte_1_file


close_1_file:
mov bx, handle
mov ah, 3eh
int 21h



mov si, offset buffer
put_char:
lodsb
mov dl,al
call putchar
dec counter
cmp counter, 0
je ending
jmp put_char

erroropening:
mov dx, offset error_open
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp ending

errorreading:
mov dx, offset error_read
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp ending


ending:
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

putchar proc
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    RET
putchar endp 


END
```

Comment: Your "loop" loop (that's a bad name btw, since `loop` is also an x86 instruction) will always exit after one iteration since you have an unconditional jump to `ending`. Also, where are you initializing `si`, and why do you expect it to become zero when printing the characters?

Comment: ok, so i tried to fix it by writing like this:
`xor si, si
get_char:
lodsb
mov dl, al
cmp al, 0
call charget
jmp ending
jmp get_char`

Comment: That's not likely to do any good. The `lodsb` instruction reads from `ds:[si]` (refer to your favorite x86 instruction set reference), so you'll want `si` to point to the start of the buffer you're going to read from. And as I mentioned before, `jmp ending` is unconditional (i.e. it will always be taken).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
close_1_file:
mov bx, handle
mov ah, 3eh
int 21h

loop:
lodsb
mov dl,al
call charget
cmp si, 0
jmp ending

jmp loop
```

First of all, you really shouldn't name a lable like an instruction.

Second, where is `si` initialized?

Third, why do you compare it against 0?

Fourth, why two jumps?

```
jmp ending ; you want this to be je
jmp loop
```

And the function `charget`  writes a character, but is named as if it were reading it?

But even if you would have the `je` to branch, where would the `0`come from? You said in your file is `abc`, so there will be no `0` in your buffer, unless you explitcitly put it there.

**update**

What you must do is the following:

1. open the file. **done**
2. read the file. **done**
3. preserve the number of bytes you just read.
4. close the file. **done**
5. point to the buffer where you read it into.
6. loop through that buffer until you have printed N characters, where N is the number of bytes you preserved from the read.

**update 2**

You still have one problem left. Of course you store each character in a row, otherwoise you read each single character in the same place.

```
mov ax, counter
mov dx, offset buffer
add dx, ax
inc counter
```

Comment: i'm trying to fix this. yeah, i should've used xor si,si.
two jmps is my dumb mistake again. 
thank you for your helpful response.

Comment: `xor si, si`  will not help you. It should be `mov si, offset buffer`, and your break condition will also not work. When you read a file, you get the number of characters read back, so you would loop over that amount of data.

Comment: i'm really sorry that i'm being so foolish, somehow i didn't paste in the `mov si, offset buffer`, that's my bad. The biggest problem for me still is the 3 point you've written. Do i have to make some sort of a counter, which does `INC` every time 1 byte is read?

Comment: Yes. When you read the file you get a number back. In this case it is 3 if your file only contains `abc`. So if you want to print each character individually, you must loop over the buffer and call print as well as keeping track of how often you have to do it. As you can see AX contains the number of bytes. http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah3f. Do you have a manual for `int 21`?

Comment: Yes, i've been using this page while trying to make this program to work. But still, i added counters, and i believe it's not what you tried to explain me. I posted updated code. Or should i push AX after the file was read and then pop it somewhere?

Comment: Looks good, at first glance it should work now. You should use `debug` to debug your program if it doesn't work.

Comment: 1 more question, if a file test.txt has `abc` and new blank line (after c i press enter), will the file be of 4 bytes?

Comment: Your algorithm reads as long as the file is long. So you must take care that you have enough memory for the file, or your must read in chunks, if the file is bigger than your buffer.