# Assembly Cannot do comparing anymore after closing file

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, masm, x86-16

I cannot understand why I cannot perform comparison anymore at `Continue` label after putting the reading file module (from `Open_File` until `Close_Error`). If I remove the reading file module, it can work.

No error while assembling and linking. No error message while running the program. The program does not crash when running. Infinite loop if I put the reading file module.
Display 3 testing if reading file module has been removed

What register actually affects this? Or which flag? How can I solve it?

File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwulv7du5k7xnb3/1.dat

```
.model small
.stack 20240
.data
    fname db '1.dat', 0
    handle dw ?
    fileLength dw 0
    openErrorMsg db "File open failed$"
    closeErrorMsg db "File close failed$"
    readErrorMsg db "File read failed$"
    buffer db ?

    tryCount db 4
    try db 0
    msg db "testing$"
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax          ; initialize DS

;----------------------------Open file----------------------------
Open_File:
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, openErrorMsg
int 21h

mov ah, 3dh         ; open file function
mov al, 0           ; open for reading  
lea dx, fname       ; copy address to DX
int 21h             ; open the file
mov handle, ax      ; handle or err code

jc Open_Error       ; jump if error
jnc Read_File

Open_Error:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, openErrorMsg
    int 21h

    ;--------------------------newline
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h

    jmp Exit

;----------------------------Read file----------------------------
Read_File:
mov ah, 3fh         ; read file 
mov bx, handle      ; copy handle into BX
mov cx, ax          ; read until EOF
lea dx, buffer
int 21h             ; AX = bytes read

lea bx, buffer              ; get the length of buffer
mov si, ax                  
mov byte ptr [bx+si], '$'   ; put terminator at the end of buffer

mov fileLength, bx
add fileLength, si
sub fileLength, 46h


jc Read_Error       ; jump if error
jnc Display

Read_Error:
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, readErrorMsg
    int 21h

    ;--------------------------newline
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h

;----------------------------Display----------------------------
Display:
mov si, 0
Decrypt:
    sub buffer[si], 20h
    xor  buffer[si], 11000011b
    inc si
    cmp si, fileLength
jne Decrypt
je Continue_Display

Continue_Display:
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, buffer
int 21h

;--------------------------newline
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h

;----------------------------Close file----------------------------
mov ah, 3eh         ; close file function
mov bx, handle      ; copy handle to bx
int 21h             ; execute closing
jc Close_Error      ; jump if error
jnc Continue

Close_Error:
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, closeErrorMsg
int 21h

;--------------------------newline
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h

;-------------------------------------------------------------

Continue:
inc try
mov al, try
cmp al, tryCount
jb Go
je Exit

Go:
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg
int 21h
jmp Continue


Exit:
;--------------------------newline
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

Comment: What does _"cannot perform comparison"_ mean? Do you get an error while assembling and linking? Do you get an error message while running the program? Does the program crash? Does it give unexpected output (in what way)..?

Comment: No error while assembling and linking. No error message while running the program. The program does not crash.

Comment: Infinite loop if I put the reading file module.

Comment: I doubt maybe the zero flag already changed after closing the file. Is there anyway to reset the zero flag?

Comment: That would not matter, since you're doing a `cmp` before the first conditional jump after `Continue:`.

Comment: However, `buffer db ?` is a mighty small buffer (just a single byte). So you're probably overwriting a bunch of other variables (like `try` and `tryCount`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you declare `buffer` to be a single byte

```
buffer db ?
```

And here you read into that single byte.

```
lea dx, buffer
int 21h             ; AX = bytes read

lea bx, buffer              ; get the length of buffer
mov si, ax                  
mov byte ptr [bx+si], '$'   ; put terminator at the end of buffer
```

so even if you would read only a single byte from the file, you are already writing beyond the limts of the buffer variable by putting the `$` at the end.

I don't know how long your input file is, but it is rather likely, that you unintentationally overwrite a bigger part of memory.

Comment: Ya. After expand the buffer size, the issue has been solved. Thanks. Is this issue so-called memory leak?

Comment: I'ts a buffer overrun, not a memory leak. A memory leak would be if you allocated memory but don't free it. For long running processes this would cause it to consume more and more memory. Would be nice if you accept the naswer then. :) BTW: I don't know how you fixced. The correct solution would be to read the file in chunks, if it is bigger then the buffer, but that of course, depends on the expected data you have to work with.

Comment: I just change it to buffer db 10240 dup("$"). :) Can you show me to read the file in chunks? I have no idea how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Reading in chunks mean, that you have to read N bytes, as long until there are no more bytes. It depends on your algorithm though, because you need to do the processing of the data in between. So you may read a certain record size (if you have some fixed or well known data structure). However it is a bit complex for a comment. You can take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500169/lodsb-tasm-outputs-only-last-letter-from-the-file and refer to the `readbyte_1_file:` which basically reads a single character after the other and prints it. You can of course read more than just a char

Comment: Can I add u facebook? :)

Comment: That wouldn't help yopu match, because I rarely use fb and usually only to keep contact with family. ;)